# Delete lines based on keywords within tags

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sed

I have a directory `.txt` files generated as an output of a Search and Extract
program. The `.txt` file is in the below format.

Based on the keyword, `Entrust`, I'm trying to remove the below lines using
`sed` as a post-processing step.

```html
<content>This document has been digitally signed with external signatures using Entrust PKI</content>
```

The `sed` command I'm running in a shell script is below:Noticed that no lines are removed from the .txt file.
Can `sed` not search and delete based on content within tags? Is there any other way I can do this?

```sh
sed '/Entrust/d' $file > ${file}.mod;
```

```html
  <block>
  <title>
This is the title
  </title>
  </block>
  <block>
  <content>
Content1
  </content>
  </block>
  <block>
  <title>
Title 2
  </title>
  <content>
some content 2
  </content>
  </block>
  <block>
  <title>
Title 3
  </title>
  <content>
some content 3
  </content>
  <content>
This document has been digitally signed with external signatures using Entrust PKI

  </content>
  <content>
some content4

  </content>
  <content>
This document has been digitally signed with external signatures using Entrust PKI
  </content>
 </block>
```

Comment: Text file says Entrust, your sed cmd looks for Entrusted

Comment: @simak Is the text file created on windows? Do you just want to remove the line containing `Entrust` or remove the tags enclosing the line as well?

Comment: I want to delete the line containing Entrust. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand you are trying to delete from the txt file. I would suggest `sed -i` for that. You should see required lines deleted in `${file}.mod` with your command

```
sed -i '/Entrust/d' $file
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

[sed](/questions/tagged/sed)

```
sed -n '/Entrust/!p' $file > ${file}.mod
```

**or**

```
sed '/Entrust/d' $file > ${file}.mod
```

[awk](/questions/tagged/awk)

```
awk '!/Entrust/' $file > ${file}.mod
```

Answer (score 0):

As has been noted, your file contains `Entrust`, yet you are searching for `Entrusted`

```sh
sed '/Entrust/d'
```

Comment: Sorry that was a typo when entering here. The command I am running is indeed: sed '/Entrust/d' $file > ${file}.mod;

Comment: @simak Please edit your question if there is a critical typo like this (I did it for you this time).

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i 's/<content>This document has been digitally signed with external signatures using Entrust PKI</content>/#<content>This document has been digitally signed with external signatures using Entrust PKI</content>/g' $filename
```

This is the way you can comment the line that will not be noticed/read by the script.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -lne 'print unless(/\bEntrust\b/)' your_file.txt > your_file.mod
```

Answer (score 0):

To search text outside XML-style tags, use the command below;

```
sed '/^\([^<]*\(<[^<>]*>\)*\)*Entrust/d'
```

Here is an example;

```
$ cat tmp.txt
some content 2.
some content with Entrust.
<tag type='Entrust'/>
<tag>Entrust</tag>
$ sed '/^\([^<]*\(<[^<>]*>\)*\)*Entrust/d' tmp.txt 
some content 2.
<tag type='Entrust'/>
```

Note that this expression does not handle a tag which contains line-breaks.